# How to make a listbox of relative item by previews item clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of cars.

```
public static List<Car> cars;
```

After I clicked an item from this static list, i want to make another list that contains relatives cars, that i can be interested in.
How can I make such a list?

Answer (score 0):

As basic example

```
private void ListBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = (Car)ListBox1.SelectedItem;

        if (!ListBox2.Items.Contains(selectedItem.Name))
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(selectedItem.Name);
        }
    }
```

OUPUT: 
[image]

I hope it helps. Happy coding.